# MODX - how to listing Static Resources of certain document ID?

Tags: file, modx

I'm playing with MODx 2.2. Does anyone knows how to easy listing "Static Resourses" from certain document ID? In my system there is a file attachments list below the content of article based on that "Static Resourses"

Comment: Please clarify your question, Do you mean "easily list" static resources located in the resource tree, or are you looking at a list of resources within the content of the article itself.

Comment: I mean a list of resources within the content of the article itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are trying to do.  But are you trying to list the child resources of a particular partent resource?  For example:

Parent
- child 
- child 
- child

If so you will need to use the getResource snippet:
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources

and example call that you would place on the page you want to display the list would be, if the parent's ID=20

```
[[getResources? &parents=`20`]]
```

If you wish to use the current page as id to list all child resources change 20 to

```
[[*id]]
```

Answer (score 1):

ok- thanks, much clearer now.

So out of the box? 'No'. But you can probably get the job done by writing a little plugin that whips through the resource content looking for the static resources [if you are unfamiliar with plugins, they are just basically snippets that execute on a system event that you define], see here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Plugins [and at the bottom an incomplete list of events] I'm thinking you have 2 options:

1. Write a plugin that fires on the  OnWebPagePrerender event that basically just whips through the resource content looking for your [[~xxx]] - It should be easy to extract these & pass them to either a custom script or getResources. I would expect some problems with caching here.
2. If it's actually just a list of static resources, and not scattered through out the resource content:
   a. place your static resource id's in a template variable [http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Template+Variables]  & extract them with getResources.
   b. follow Ben's answer and setup your static resources as children of your document resource.